# Mysql difference between AI and G?

Tags: mysql

Hi I am very new to coding. I am trying to make my own own mysql database that I can experiment with. I made my first table and I am trying to get it to auto generate the ID. Which column flag to choose. AI or G? What is the difference?

Comment: Sounds like you use some (graphical) client? You should mention which one.

Comment: If `AI` means `Auto Increment`, that's the correct option. I can't think of what `G` means.

Comment: Oh, `G` probably means `Generated`. This is a virtual column that's computed automatically from other columns, and has nothing to do with the ID.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html for information about Generated columns.

Comment: Yes, those are what they mean. I use mysql workbench. Are you saying AI is used to Auto Increment in the primary key? And Generated is for if I had something else like a date?

Comment: Actually I just read the link you posted. Thanks so much!

Comment: Note that you are not allowed to make a given column both auto-increment and generated.